# Refactoring two variants of the same code

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, refactoring

I'm not a dev, more like a designer. I have a calendar on two different pages, and it should behave differently one these two pages. So I modified the code a bit for it to happen, and it did when I tested it.
BUT now I have to integrate both these variants together and of course gulp can't compile because of an "already defined" error. So i tried to merge them with a bit of logic but I'm a noob so I need your help please.
Here are the two bits, and what I tried to do, but I'm sure it's wrong

```
// Field used on the calendar view.
var dateFromFilter = $("#dateFromFilter").not($(".unlimitedDateFilter"))
.fdatepicker($.extend({}, datepickerCommonOptions, {
    onRender: function(date) {
        return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? "disabled" : "";
    }
}))
.on("changeDate", function(ev) {
    if (ev.date.valueOf() > dateToFilter.date.valueOf()) {
        var newDate = new Date(ev.date);
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
        dateToFilter.update(newDate);
    }
    dateFromFilter.hide();
    $("#dateToFilter")[0].focus();
})
.data("datepicker");


// Field used on the sales results view
var dateFromFilter = $("#dateFromFilter.unlimitedDateFilter")
.fdatepicker($.extend({}, datepickerCommonOptions))
.on("changeDate", function(ev) {
    if (ev.date.valueOf() > dateToFilter.date.valueOf()) {
        var newDate = new Date(ev.date);
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
        dateToFilter.update(newDate);
    }
    dateFromFilter.hide();
    $("#dateToFilter")[0].focus();
})
.data("datepicker");
```

My try :

```
var dateFromFilter = $("#dateFromFilter")

if ($("dateFromFilter").hasClass(unlimitedDateFilter))  {
    $.fdatepicker($.extend({}, datepickerCommonOptions))
}
else    {  
    $.fdatepicker($.extend({}, datepickerCommonOptions, {
        onRender: function(date) {
            return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? "disabled" : "";
        }
    }))
}

$.on("changeDate", function(ev) {
    if (ev.date.valueOf() > dateToFilter.date.valueOf()) {
        var newDate = new Date(ev.date);
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
        dateToFilter.update(newDate);
    }
    dateFromFilter.hide();
    $("#dateToFilter")[0].focus();
})
.data("datepicker");
```

Thank you for your help

EDIT :

Thank you for your suggestions, I tried to put the condition in the onRender, but it doesn't work. I think I need to encapsulate the onRender itself in the condition, but I have no idea about how the syntax should be.

```
// Field used on the sales results view
    var dateFromFilter = $("#dateFromFilter")
    .fdatepicker($.extend({}, datepickerCommonOptions, {
        onRender: function(date) {
            if (!$("dateFromFilter").hasClass("unlimitedDateFilter")) {
                return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? "disabled" : "";
            }
        }
    }))
    .on("changeDate", function(ev) {
        if (ev.date.valueOf() > dateToFilter.date.valueOf()) {
            var newDate = new Date(ev.date);
            newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
            dateToFilter.update(newDate);
        }
        dateFromFilter.hide();
        $("#dateToFilter")[0].focus();
    })
    .data("datepicker");
```

Comment: You should go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and ask there for refractoring help.

Comment: if the only thing different is your onrender, why not do a check inside that for hasClass and then do stuff based on that?